# How to do encryption/decyption using crypto js in ionic4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, encryption, cryptojs, caesar-cipher

I am trouble, how to do encryption/decyption using crypto js in ionic4?

I have written code for encryption decryption in java

```
public static String encrypt(String str) 
{
    String encryptedString = str;

    try {
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] enc = encryptor.doFinal(utf8);
        encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(enc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encryptedString;
}
```

For **decryption**

```
public static String decrypt(String str) 
{
    String decryptedString = "";        
    try {
        byte[] dec = Base64.decodeBase64(str);
        byte[] utf8 = decryptor.doFinal(dec);
        decryptedString = new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return decryptedString;
}
```

**Secrete key generation**

```
public static void genKeyPair(int i)    {
    try {
        // generates DES key from string //
        key = new SecretKeySpec(Skey.getBytes(), "DES");

        // initialize the cipher with key //
        encryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        decryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        encryptor.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        decryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        System.err.println(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to write same thing in ionic4, how to do plz help me. I am new in ionic4(Hybrid application)

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-cryptography/cipher.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like custom encryption/decryption,You can use one of the many encryption methods like from crypto-js like:

Its pretty simple, here is **sample code to go-ahead** :

```
import * as utf8 from 'crypto-js/enc-utf8';
import * as AES from 'crypto-js/aes';

// Encryption
AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data),your_encKey).toString();

// Decryption
AES.decrypt(userdata, your_encKey).toString(utf8);
```

For More : **[READ HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)**

> **I think this code snippet is enough reference to go ahead and will
>   help you to convert your code with ionic4/angular.**

Comment: How to generate secret key in ionic 4?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in angular (IONIC 4) , but sign characters are differs from java code

```
let key="AND$VBOA";
var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
var message = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(message, keyHex, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
console.log("Encrypted:="+encrypted.toString());
```

for decryped

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted)
}, keyHex, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
console.log("Derypted:="+decrypted .toString());
```

In ionic

```
Ecrypted: 6qPw1YkOopA=
Decrypted: Nitin
```

In Java

```
Ecrypted: 6qPw1YkOopA
Decrypted: Nitin
```

In Ionic

```
Ecrypted: oOmH6uQ4R/Q=
Decrypted: Message
```

In Java

```
Ecrypted: oOmH6uQ4R_Q
Decrypted: Message
```

In Ionic

```
Ecrypted: f+eTKAqlUwXnznPVyjTXWA==
Decrypted: engineer
```

In Java

```
Ecrypted: f-eTKAqlUwXnznPVyjTXWA
Decrypted: engineer
```

So many example tested in Java "-" & in IONIC "+"  & in ionic "/" & java "_", In ionic extra  = or == are  comming. Then whats wrong in this sample code, Plz suggest me.